# “Take something into control"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is it correct to say “he took something into control”? For example, “After being pushed about by the whims of fate, he finally took his destiny into control."

Comment: No, but you might say "he finally took control of his destiny".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two phrases here:

- [to take control **of**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+control+of) and
- [to take matters<sup>1</sup> **into** your own hands](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/take-matters-into-your-own-hands)

So you should decide for one, either:

> - After being pushed about by the whims of fate, he finally **took control of** his destiny.

or:

> - After being pushed about by the whims of fate, he finally **took** his destiny **into his own hands**."

---

<sup>1</sup> or in this case: "your destiny".

Answer (score 1):

It's not idiomatic to say "into control".  [With "control", we usually say something is **under control**.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+into+control%2Cit+under+control%2Cit+in+control&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20into%20control%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20under%20control%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20in%20control%3B%2Cc0)  Even "in control" is more idiomatic than "into control".  ([*Into* is usually used with motion towards something.](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/in-to-or-into))

Beyond that, it's more idiomatic to say [**he took control of his destiny**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=took%20control%20of%2Ctook%20*%20under%20control&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctook%20control%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctook%20it%20under%20control%3B%2Cc0), rather than "he took his destiny into/under control".